# How to add values to the first row and the first column of two dimensional array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, loops, multidimensional-array, multiple-columns

I am trying to add numbers from 0 to 9 in the row and 0 to 11 in column of a two dimensional array in C. And as for the rest of the empty spaces, I would like to add 0.

The matrix size is 9 x 11. And this is what the output looks like with the empty blocks filled with 0:
[image]

And this is the code I have so far but it does not work:

```
int i;
int j;
int arr[i][j];

int value = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < 11; j++){
        arr[i][j] = value;
        printf("%d\n", arr[i][j]);
        value++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: How does it not work? I would assume you run into issues because you have not set the values of i and j when you initialize the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot that you've posted has 10 rows and 12 columns, so assuming that, here is the code:

```
int i;
int j;
int arr[10][12];

for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            arr[0][j] = j;
        } else if (j == 0) {
            arr[i][0] = i;
        } else {
            arr[i][j] = 0;
        }

        printf("%d", arr[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
}
```